# Laplace transform to solve differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, partial-fractions

The differential equation is as follows-

> $$y′′+4y′-5y=te^t$$
>   $$y(0)=1,y′(0)=0$$

$L[{y′′+4y′-5y}]=L{y′′}+4L{y′}-5L{y}=[s^2L{y}−sy(0)−y′(0)]+4[sL{y}−y(0)]-5L{y}=L{y}(s^2+4s-5)+s+4$

$L(te^t)= \frac{1}{(s-1)^2}$

$L(y)=\frac{1}{(s-1)^2} + s+4 $

After this I can't find the  to perform partial fraction decomposition. Can you help me please? Thanks!!

Comment: Would you be interested in seeing a solution to the second order differential equation through a different method (such as undetermined coefficients)?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to solve by another method? The exercise required to account for the laplace transform. Thanks!

Comment: I have solved the boundary value problem by the method of undetermined coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(s^2+4s-5)=(s-1)(s+5)$ we have:
$$Y(s)=\frac {s+4}{(s-1)(s+5)}+\frac 1 {(s-1)^3(s+5)}$$
$$Y(s)=g(s)+f(s)$$
The first fraction is easy to decompose:
$$g(s)=\frac {s+4}{(s-1)(s+5)}=\frac A {s-1}+\frac B {s+5}$$
$A=\frac 5 6$ and $B=\frac 16$
$$\implies y_h(t)=\mathcal {L^{-1}}\{g(s)\}=\frac 5 6e^t+\frac 16e^{-5t}$$
It's the solution to the homogeneous equation with the given initial conditions.

---

For the particular solution here is a little help:
$$f(s)=\frac 1 {(s-1)^3(s+5)}$$
$$f(s)=\frac {A}{(s-1)^3}+\frac {B}{(s-1)^2}+\frac {C}{(s-1)}+\frac {D}{(s+5)}$$
We have
$$A=\frac 16 \text { And } D=-\frac 1 {6^3}$$
Note that since $D,C$ are the only fraction with $s^3$ at the numerator so we can deduce that $C=-D=\frac 1 {6^3}$
For B  you need to calculate...